# Roman Numbers on ordered doesn't work because of CSS

Tags: html, css, html-lists, css-counter

I was looking for a way to create a nested ordered list with numbers like this

```
1.
   1.1
   1.2
2.
   2.1
   2.2
```

I have it working in fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uuexmbrv/)

The problem is when I change the type of `ol` to roman numbers `type="I"` it doesn't work because of the CSS I added.

```
    <ol type="I">
    <li>Elemento primero
        <ol type="I">
            <li>Subelemento primero</li>
            <li>Subelemento segundo</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>elemento segundo</li>
</ol>
    <ol type="I">
        <li>Subelemento primero</li>
        <li>Subelemento segundo</li>
    </ol>
```

CSS:

```
OL {
    counter-reset: item
}
LI {
    display: block
}
LI:before {
    content: counters(item, ".")" ";
    counter-increment: item
}
```

Comment: Did the answer help you (or) are you looking for something more/different? If you are looking for something else more, please [edit] the question and add more details.

Answer (score 3):

You are using CSS counters to display the nested numbering and unlike default `ol`, the output format does not change with the `type="I"` attribute. You have to set the counter's output format to be roman numbers explicitly. By default, the output format is decimal numbers but all styles that are available for the `list-style-type` property are also available for counters (**Source**: [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#counter-styles)).

This can be achieved by passing `upper-roman` (equivalent to `type="I"`) or `lower-roman` (equivalent to `type="i"`) as one of the parameter values to the `counters()` or `counter()` function.

```css
OL {
  counter-reset: item
}
LI {
  display: block
}
LI:before {
  content: counters(item, ".", upper-roman)" ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol type="I">
  <li>Elemento primero
    <ol type="I">
      <li>Subelemento primero</li>
      <li>Subelemento segundo</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>elemento segundo</li>
</ol>
<ol type="I">
  <li>Subelemento primero</li>
  <li>Subelemento segundo</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Damn..been trying to get that to work in JSFiddle for the past 5 minutes...must have missed a comma somewhere,

Comment: @Paulie_D: I did something exactly similar to that and was breaking my head for 3-4 minutes :P

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - you just needed to set your content as upper-roman.

```
OL {
    counter-reset: section;
}
LI {
    display: block;
    counter-reset: number;
}
LI:before {
    counter-increment: section;
    content: "Section " counter(section, upper-roman) ". ";
}
```